# How to change item names in CKEditor "Format" menu?

Tags: ckeditor

I need to change the option names in the "Format" menu in CKEditor. For instance, I want to change "Normal" to "Paragraph".

I understand that one way to do it is to edit the language file (`en.js`). But I don't want to mess up the original sourcecode because it will make the upgrade to a future version much harder.

I tried to change the value `CKEDITOR.lang.en.tag_p` at runtime before initializing the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.lang.en.tag_p = "Paragraph";
CKEDITOR.replace(...);
```

It didn't work because the language file is not loaded at this point (`lang.en` is `undefined`).

I also tried to use event handlers (`instanceLoaded` and `loaded`) - no success.

Changing the language values on `instanceLoaded` seems to be too late. It still shows the default values in the menu.

And `loaded` event never fires for some reason.

I found a solution that involves overriding `CKEDITOR.plugins.load`, but I think it's too much for such a simple task.

Is there a simple and elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following solution: load the English language file before creating editor instance, and update it using callback once it is loaded.

```
CKEDITOR.lang.load("en", "en", function() {
  CKEDITOR.lang.en.format.tag_p = "Paragraph";
  CKEDITOR.lang.en.format.tag_h2 = "Header";
  CKEDITOR.lang.en.format.tag_h3 = "Sub-Header";
});
// Init editor here
```

I personally don't like it, but it's the best I could do.